# Why can't codewars accept my answer? Im trying to practice in codewars using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am a newbie and Im trying to practice codes with codewars. The problem is I already solve the problem, but it wont accept my codes.

Here's the problem:

[image]

Here's my solution:

```js
function descendingOrder(n){    
  var result =(n.toString().split('').reverse().sort(function(a, b){return b-a}).join(''));     
   parseFloat(result); 
   return result; 
  
}
console.log(descendingOrder(12345));
```

What I tried is of course removing the parameter in function which is 12345 since codewars has already done it.

Comment: why do you have reverse and sort it later? if you have already a sorted array, you could reverse. or sort if not sorted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some unnecessary functionality (like `reverse()`) in your code. In addition I understood you're dealing with integers, not floats:

```js
const descendingOrder = (n) => {    
  const result = n.toString().split('').sort((a, b) => b - a).join('');     

  return parseInt(result); 
};

console.log(descendingOrder(123454821));
```

Comment: Hey thank you very muchh!!. Now it works , but hmm I dont understand how .sort((a, b) => b - a) works. Idk how did u changed it, but I'm gonna find out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could sort by default sorting and reverse the array, like

```
return +value
    .toString()
    .split('')
    .sort()     // sort by string asc
    .reverse()
    .join('');
```

or sort with a callback descending and omit reversing.

```
return +value
    .toString()
    .split('')
    .sort((a, b) => b - a)
    .join('');
```